# 2TB Seagate Expansion Portable Hard Drive not appearing in Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

I know this has been asked before but I wanted some help ASAP so recently my Seagate 2TB External Hard Drive was working fine, then all of a sudden it stopped working while I was copying some JPEGs to my Desktop. I thought it was weird so I force ejected my hard drive and tried plugging it back in to see if that'd work. Now it won't show up at all. Not in my Disk Utility, or Finder or even desktop. I ran a "diskutil list" in my terminal and it wouldn't even show up there. The ONLY place it shows any signs of life are; The blue light is on indicating that it has power, and in my About This Mac --> System Report --> USB, it shows up as "Expansion" and has the same S/N as my hard drive so I can confirm that they're one and the same. This is a huge inconvenience to me and since I only bought this product about a month ago I was expecting a lot more out of it. I've never damaged it in any way and have lots of important data stored on this hard drive. I'd really appreciate any help.[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the HD died in the middle of being used. If you have another computer to plug it into you could verify this. May be time to replace the drive.

Comment: See my first reaction was, huh maybe my laptop is messing up... So I plugged it into 2 other computers and still no luck :/ I don't care too much about the drive but more so the data on it. If I could just recover the files, it would save my life

Comment: There is software that **might** do it. There are also company's that specialize in data recovery. The latter can be expensive. Just search for mac data recovery and you should get some hits on software and companies